Unable to load image in raylib
I am building a frogger game in c++ using raylib 5.0 and visual studio 2022, I am trying to load an image, but when I run the program, I get a black screen with no image.
below is my code:
Source.cpp:
#include "player.h"
#include "raylib.h"

int main() {
  int winWidth = 800;
  int winHeight = 800;

  InitWindow(winWidth, winHeight, "Frogger Game");
  SetTargetFPS(60);

  player frog;

  while (WindowShouldClose() == false) {
    BeginDrawing();
    frog.Draw();

    EndDrawing();
  }

  CloseWindow();
}

player.h :
#pragma once
#include <raylib.h>

class player {
 private:
  Texture2D image;
  Vector2 position;

 public:
  player();
  ~player();
  void Draw();
  void Move();
};

player.cpp:
#include "player.h"

player::player() {
  image = LoadTexture("./Frog/up.png");
  position.x = (static_cast<float>(GetScreenWidth()) - image.width) / 2;
  position.y = GetScreenHeight() - image.height;
}

player::~player() { UnloadTexture(image); }

void player::Draw() { DrawTextureV(image, position, RAYWHITE); }

when i hover over "LoadTexture("./Frog/up.png")" the image shows up, so visual studio can find the folder with the image, it just doesn't load the image onto the screen. I'm not sure where i'm going wrong.

image = LoadTexture("./Frog/up.png"); try an absolute path.  The current working directory is probably not where you think it is at runtime.  If the absolute path works then use GetModuleFileName and use the returned path to create an absolute the path to the image.

The image is probably not in the application's working directory. The default working directory if you launch from within VS is the directory where the executable file is.

Always, always, when you open a file, load something from disk etc. etc. check that it works! It takes two minutes to add a check to your code and it will save you hours when it almost inevitably goes wrong. Just because Visual Studio can find the image is no guarantee that your program, when it runs, will also be able to find the image.

Obviously to get a precise answer to your question you need to describe how your project is structured and where the image is in that project.

@john the image is in the resource file section in visual studio. The cpp file is stored in source files section.

I am not sure that raylib will load from a windows resource. You may have to not put it in the windows resource or have your executable extract the resource at runtime as a normal file and then specify the path you extracted.

Here is a reddit topic about this: https://www.reddit.com/r/raylib/comments/ub09iq/how_to_bundle_assets_with_compiled_executable/

There is also this video that explains the ExportImageAsCode: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6l4S7bexGtg

@user22428402 That does not tell me where the files are on the hard disk. Source sections/Resource sections are not relevant when your program starts running. The two things that do matter (probably) are the directory where your solution/project file is, and the directory where this image is. Where your cpp file is, is also irrelevant.

@drescherjm By resource section I think the OP means the virtual folder that exists in Visual Studio for resource like files. I don't think the OP is actually distributing the image as a resource.

@user22428402 Probably the best bet to make progress is the suggestion that Richard Critten made. Find out where the image file is on the hard disk. Then try to load is using the full path. I.e. something starting C:/.... This avoids the issue of the current working directory, which seems to be a concept you are not familiar with.
